# Thresholding for tiff stack looks at entire stack instead of individual tiff image

Tags: matlab, threshold, imagej, adaptive-threshold

I have a tiff stack (b/w) and when I open individual images from the stack in imageJ, the contrast is perfect, however, when i open the entire stack (image sequence of moving things), the contrast is terrible for the end slides (where fluorescence has of course, bleached out). IS there a way in either Matlab or imageJ to ensure that the contrast is determined not by the entire stack, but by the individual images in the stack (so that this change in brightness is no longer there).

Let me know how i can explain better. It's a really simple problem, but I don't know how easy it is to understand without seeing.

thanks

Comment: This question seems to be rather an image analysis question than a [specific programming problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), therefore I suggest to direct your question to the [ImageJ users mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html).

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure where to go.

Answer (score 1):

To correct a fluorescence signal bleaching over time, consider using the [bleach corrector plugin](http://cmci.embl.de/downloads/bleach_corrector) for ImageJ.
When thresholding a stack in ImageJ you can calculate the threshold separately for each slice:

- *Image > Adjust > Threshold...*

[image: ImageJ threshold dialog]

- leave *Stack histogram* unchecked to get a preview for the threshold calculated based on the current slice
- click on *Apply*

[image]

- in the dialog, choose *Calculate threshold for each image* to apply the chosen thresholding method to each stack slice separately.

In order to get the macro source code for this procedure, start the [ImageJ macro recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-14.html#toc-Section-14) via *Plugins > Macros > Record...* before starting.